# Utility to compare json file with oracle table data

Tags: python, json, list

I have a JSON file like below:

```
{
  "RequestId": 12345,
  "RequestData": {
    "Table1": {
      "REQUEST_ID": 12345.0,
      "Column1": "xyz",
      "column2": 56
    },
    "Table2": {
      "columnn3": 1.0,
      "COL4_ID": 12345.0,
      "col5": "X",
      "STRATEGY_ID": "0",
      "WARNING_LEVEL": "0"
    },
    "Table3": {
      "CHECK_TYPE": "X",
      "HASERROR": 0,
      "TOTAL_TIME_MS": 14.1788
    }
  },
  "Others": [
    {
      "Table8": {
        "REQUEST_ID": 12345.0,
        "Column11": "xyz",
        "column21": 56
      },
      "Table21": {
        "columnn31": 1.0,
        "COL41_ID": 12345.0,
        "col8": "X",
        "STRATEGY_ID": "0",
        "WARNING_LEVEL": "0"
      },
      "Table32": {
        "CHECK_TYPE": "X",
        "HASERROR": 0,
        "TOTAL_TIME_MS": 14.1788
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The tables and columns within can vary, I need to build something to compare the values here with the values in an Oracle database, the table and column names match exactly in the database too.

How can I traverse though all the table list in file?

eg:

1) I will create the list of tables within file something like below. How can I identify only tables in the file, so that I can traverse through to produce something which would help to compare the values stored in the database?

```py
list1 = [
    'Table1'
    'Table2',
    'Table3',
    'Table8',
    'Table21',
    'Table32'
]
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON. You should run it through [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/?code=) befrehand to fix any formatting errors.

Comment: Have corrected and validated the Json ,